# Vaadin Maven Build Properties in HTML file

Tags: html, maven, build, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 with Custom Layout which includes About.html file. This file contains buildId and Version information like below.

**aboutview.html**

```
<p>
    Version: ${buildVersion}<br /> Build id: ${buildId}<br />
</p>
```

**myui/pom.xml file**

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd HHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <buildTimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTimestamp>
    <buildVersion>2.0.0</buildVersion>
    <buildId>${buildTimestamp}</buildId>
</properties>
org.apache.maven.plugins maven-war-plugin true WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/, WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/

                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/abstheme/layouts</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>aboutview.html</include>
                        </includes>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>

            </configuration>
        </plugin></plugins></build>
```

How do I make sure, the properties values are available in aboutview.html once deployed in Tomcat Server?

TIA

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. [Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) the resource will replace the placeholder/variable during build time, so you will actually have the version embedded in the `aboutview.html` page at runtime. What am I missing here?

Comment: Filtering is not replacing variables/placeholder after the build. The aboutview.html page still contains $buildId and $version placeholder than the value. My problem is to replace the placeholders with value not working

Comment: Which file still has the variables, the one in you (re)soureces, or the one in the target directory (or in the resulting war)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this documentation,  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html, you can create a "resource2" folder at the root of your project and place your file there.

Then, in your pom.xml, you would add the following configuration

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>resource2</directory>
                        <targetPath>VAADIN/themes/abstheme/layout</targetPath>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Tulio, the <targetPath> tag solved the problem.